# c# - Stop all the threads started from a Form

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a form variable number of instances of which are created and shown in the runtime based on the user action. Each form instance starts a thread on its construction. The thread needs to run as long as the Form exst.

Now, I want the instances to stop the thread it started on its `FormClosing` event. How do I do that?

UPDATE:
The thread updates the text of the Textbox in the form in a certain interval. The interval is provided by the `Thread.Sleep()` method in the subroutine which is run by the thread.

Comment: There's no question in your post. Only a requirement.

Comment: What you do in the thread?

Comment: @Adil The thread updates a textbox in the form in a certain interval.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a simple [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The threads need to run continuously as long as the form exist!

Comment: OK, next question. Any reason why you can't simply set a Boolean variable to "true" (or false), and have the "interval" code exit on the right value?

Comment: If you are using timer for regular interval exectution then stop the timer in the form closing event

Comment: @Adil My bad! But it doesn't use timer. Actually the thread runs as long as the form exist!

Comment: What does the thread do? (and we already know that it updates a textbox at regular intervals, so let's consider this in terms of code)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Correct me if I am wrong but do I need to explain more when I ask I need to stop the thread a particular form started on its `FormClosing` event? Can't this be achieved disregarding whatever the thread does?

Comment: It really sounds like you should be using a timer instead of a dedicated thread for this.

Comment: It's not clear to me, why you can't use a timer. The timer can also run "continuously" in intervals. OTOH - you would end the thread in FormClosing as anywhere else. Keep a list of bools or ManualResetEvents and threads and wait for the thread after signaling the bool or event.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen A couple of other thread needs to run on the form too. Using a timer will engage the form because the thread fetches the data from the Web and that may take a while!

Comment: Use a System.Threading.Timer!

Comment: @JeffRSon how does that help?

Comment: It won't block your form. How it may help depends on your actual problem that you don't tell.